# Does any one know where the RenderAction HtmlHelper is in ASP.NET MVC in RC1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Does anyone have an alternative to the RenderAction HtmlHelper seeing as it's gone in RC1.

I need to render a user control but use a different controller to populate the user control view.

How might this work now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `Microsoft.Web.Mvc` namespace (known as MVC Futures) found in at http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=22359

It includes a HtmlHelper method (`Html.RenderAction`) which calls an action on a different controller.